# Quick high-level sizing change estimate of heat exchanger loops when adding a second loop to a simple system

Tags: heat-transfer

Say that I have a tank full of a hot liquid metal at ~700K. I want to passively remove heat using a Na loop with a Na-air heat exchanger. So I put in the loop, and I know it removes 100 kW. The Na loop has given dimensions (e.g., heat exchanger dimension, height of the loop, area occupied in the tank).
To get an idea of what it looks like, it would be very similar to this: https://ars.els-cdn.com/content/image/1-s2.0-S0951832097001695-gr3.gif

Now, I would like to see if I have a "good feel" for the system: I want to keep to the same heat removal of 100 kW, but this time with two Na loops. How do the dimensions of the Na loops change?

Can I estimate it roughly by saying: "Well, since it's all linear relationships between the Q and the dimensions, the two Na loops should now be around half the dimensions of the one-loop case"?

Is that reasoning mostly ok? Or completely off?

Comment: So assuming that the surface area will be shared is ok, but then consider that a pipe will then have a smaller diameter and that will adversely affect the flow rate. Increasing the flow may not help as the boundary layer effects change. Heat transfer with fluid flow is challenging. Check out Engineering Heat Transfer by Simonson.